# Debugging an error in the enumerate environment linked to {\quote text}

Tags: errors, enumerate

The following is a minimal working example of my document that is giving an error. Whenever I delete or comment out one of the `{\quote text}` lines, the error goes away. The line that LaTeX says is giving the problem is line 29: `\item Where hast thou been since I saw thee, I saw thee?` What is going on?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

{\quote The tale is based on an actual band}

{\quote The term ``Ackee" }

{\quote There's an old Australian}

{\quote Origin possibly}

{\quote Stand up}

\section{On Ilkley Moor Ba-Tat} \index{ On Ilkley Moor Ba-Tat}

{\quote (Standard English: On Ilkley Moor without your hat).}

\medskip

\begin{enumerate}
\item Where hast thou been since I saw thee, I saw thee?

On Ilkley moor Ba-Tat.

Where hast thou been since I saw, thee, I saw thee? ($\times$3)

On Ilkley moor Ba-Tat.($\times$3)

\medskip

\item Thou'st been a-courting Mary Jane, Mary Jane

\item That's where thou'lt catch thy death of cold

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The reason why I used the quote environment is to distinguish a description of a song from the actual lyrics:

[image: Song lyrics]

Comment: `quote` is an envirnment, moreover a list. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have the quoted text because it looks different from the main body of the text. It is out of context because it is a MWE.

Comment: What do you want to achieve then? Describe that and somebody will give you a solution. You cannot wrongly misuse `quote`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you get an error when you type in the MWE?

Comment: Of course i do.

Comment: Then can you please tell me why the error happens?

Comment: Because you are using `\quote`, which is a list, and you cannot use lists for that. Or you have to properly use them. `quote` is an environment. Hence my initial question, what do you want to get in the end, so somebody can give you an alternative solution.

Comment: I am compiling a song book. There are about 80 songs, and about 30 of them have a description of the song like Ilkley Moor Ba-Tat, before the actual lyrics. This particular song is the first time that I tried to create the enumerate environment. I decided to create the enumerate environment because I wanted the numbers to be in line (as they are in a enumerate environment). I just want this song to have a number before each different line.

Comment: I guess I've been using `quote` incorrectly.

Comment: @ahorn: There's a `songbook` package, perhaps the better option (I've never used it however, since I have not typeset songs so far)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `quote` is an environment, it is wrong to use `\quote` in the document body.
2. Using `\quote` inside the document body is wrong: you start a list environment and don't close it.
3. Using `\quote` inside a group makes everything go awry.
4. *Don't* use `\quote` in the document body.

Is it clear that `\quote` is not a command to be used in the document body?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand\squote[1]{%
  \begin{quote}#1\end{quote}%
}

\begin{document}

\squote{The tale is based on an actual band}

\squote{The term ``Ackee" }

\squote{There's an old Australian}

\squote{Origin possibly}

\squote{Stand up}

\section{On Ilkley Moor Ba-Tat} \index{ On Ilkley Moor Ba-Tat}

\squote{(Standard English: On Ilkley Moor without your hat).}

\medskip

\begin{enumerate}
\item Where hast thou been since I saw thee, I saw thee?

On Ilkley moor Ba-Tat.

Where hast thou been since I saw, thee, I saw thee? ($\times$3)

On Ilkley moor Ba-Tat.($\times$3)

\medskip

\item Thou'st been a-courting Mary Jane, Mary Jane

\item That's where thou'lt catch thy death of cold

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]